# Prove that 3 functions with a common accumulation point have a limit at that accumulation point.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f,g,h:D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, and that $x_0$ is an accumulation point of $D$. Suppose $f(x)\leq g(x)\leq h(x)$ for all $x\in D$, and $f$ and $h$ have limits at $x_0$ with $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}h(x)$.

Prove that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}g(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}h(x).$$

Comment: Where are you finding trouble?

Comment: It seems a little disingenuous to say "squeeze involved" -- you are essentially asking for a proof of the squeeze theorem.

Comment: @NicholasR.Peterson alright. I was just trying to make the title more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

This is very much a "follow your nose" type of proof.

Let $\epsilon>0$. Because the limits of $f$ and $h$ as $x\rightarrow x_0$ both exist and are equal (call their common value $L$), you can find $\delta>0$ so that $x\in D$ and $\lvert x-x_0\rvert<\delta$ implies
$$
L-\epsilon< f(x)<L+\epsilon\qquad\text{and}\qquad L-\epsilon<h(x)<L+\epsilon.
$$
How can you use this, along with the assumption $f(x)\leq g(x)\leq h(x)$, to show that $\lvert g(x)-L\rvert<\epsilon$?